# Problems sending two querys to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello the first query is executed fine.. the second one is failing.. why?, i think its ok..

I know the first part its ok , because this data its saved in the database, the second query isn´t.

```
//insert the row into the database

    $res2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `rtime`, `ms`, `ms2`) VALUES('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."','".$registerTime."','".$ms."','".$ms2."')");

    $userid = mysql_insert_id();


    $sql17 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `jugadores` (`userid`, `name`, `lastname`) VALUES('".$userid."','".$name."','".$lastname."')");
```

Comment: what is the type of userid? if integer then do not use `'`

Comment: =O ! you mean here! right '".$userid."'?

Comment: here is how to see your error `$sql17 = mysql_query(...) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());`

Comment: Thanks so much, i found the Error... do i have to close this question??

Comment: Don't forget to [Sanatize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) [your](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) [data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: like ... mysql_real_escape_string($res2),

Comment: [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good information about sanitizing/preventing SWL injection attacks.

Comment: @JulesMartinez if you have solved your error the best thing is to answer your own question and mark it correct

Answer (score 1):

User ID is an integer so this is making a problem

```
'".$userid."'
```

The correct syntax for int. numbers is

```
".$userid."
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `userid` is a primary key . So you got the problem .you can put your error in google and search the answer